# Set Extjs Panel's Height (Layout) After It's Child items taken their height

Tags: extjs

How can we recalculate the Extjs-4 Panel's Height After it's Child items like Grid (Which have auto height) takes their height.

Answer (score 1):

Use `autoHeight` with Panel and GridPanel. Then catch the **resize** event of GridPanel to force Panel to layout :

```
    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

    listeners: {
        'resize': function () {
            var panel = Ext.getCmp('panel');
            panel.doLayout();
        }
    }
}),
```

Comment: Won't this go into an infinite loop ? Because doLayout() will call trigger resize again ...